# Modifying Heisenberg's Unified field theory with gravity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-gravity, unified-theories

How would Heisenberg's unified field equations (as presented in [*"Introduction to Unified Field Theory of Elementary Particles"*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-61742-3_62) by Heisenberg) be represented if gravity is incorporated? Would it result in a case similar to the [Heisenberg-Ivanenkov equation](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=Heisenberg+Ivanenko*), or am I just confused here?

I would really appreciate if the Heisenberg-Ivanenkov equation's essence is explained as there is no firm online source to provide more information.

Comment: This paper is not free to download.

Comment: @mas  Precisely the reason I posted the question here. I want some person who has info on this topic to enlighten me. Please do tell me if you find an alternate place where this article is available

Comment: @Balaji, so far my knowledge is concerned, It was Heisenberg and Pauli who   put forward a model for unification. But later it was abandoned as the paper had flaws. I did not read the original paper, but Michio Kaku touched this subject (model of Heisenberg) in his book hyperspace.

Comment: @mas And do you have any info on the Heisenberg-Ivanenkov equation?

Comment: @Balaji, never heared of it.  i think Heisenberg-Ivanenkov equation is not a standard result.

Comment: @mas ok, thanks! Please do inform me if you happen to find any info on it in any book or anywhere online. And the michio kaku book(hyperspace) you were talking about, does it have  a brief info about the topic or is it merely a mention?

Comment: @AMS: Are you sure that "the paper had **flaws**"? I also read Michio Kaku's book but couldn't find him making this specific claim. Can you mention the source of your claim? The only thing that I found relevant was that Heisenberg's Unified Field Equations were technically difficult, which doesn't necessarily mean that it was **flawed**, am I correct?

Comment: Furthermore see [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDAQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftheor.jinr.ru%2F~spin2012%2Ftalks%2Fs5%2FObukhov.pdf&ei=2SIuVObjIse8ugSzp4C4DA&usg=AFQjCNGbeQa83EwMhJBexbwVB4hfUnHdhg&bvm=bv.76802529,d.c2E).

Comment: One thing you must know that marriage between QM and GR is highly non-trivial. At present string theory of M-theory presumably the best hope we have towards this direction. Why don't you go through any standard text book string theory to see how actually one can achieve such a unification. Let me ask: do you know the technical details how someone can unify rest three interactions except gravity based on symmetry of Lie group?

Comment: @AMS: "[D]o you know the technical details how someone can unify rest three interactions except gravity based on symmetry of Lie group?"-No. You said that "it was abandoned as the paper had flaws" and I merely wanted to know the source of your claim. Can you mention it please? Also can you clarify the reason behind your saying the last two sentences of your comment (I am sorry, but I can't figure out the relevance of them so long as my previous comments are concerned)?

Comment: Probably you have lost interest in this topic. But it seems to me that  V. Dzhunushaliev is an expert in Heisenberg's Nonliear Spinor Field Theory so it may be a good idea to write to him regarding this issue. In particular you can read [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9810050.pdf).

Comment: @user170039 Thanks a ton!